# Selenium browser usernamd and password popups - unable to handle (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Having problems with a login script.
User navigates to the siteA.  At this point enters and email address and clicks a button.  User is then redirected to siteB which displays a browser authentication window for username and password.  Once this has been entered, the user is redirected back to siteA.

This should be easy to do, I thought.  However when I come upon the browser authentication popup I cannot switch to it.  I am also seeing that the old UserAndPassword import isn't working anymore (I am using 3.9.0)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url      = "url";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","resources/GeckoDriver/v0.19.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // open the browser and navigate to the url
        driver.get(url);

        // set some window size and timeouts
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // enter text
        driver.findElement(By.name("loginfmt")).sendKeys("emailAdd");

        // click login button
        driver.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9")).click();

        Alert windowAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        UserAndPassword uAp = new UserAndPassword(username, password);

        windowAlert.authenticateUsing(uAp);

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();     

    }

}
```

I thought the username and password stuff was stored in import org.openqa.selenium.security.* but couldn't get that.  Has this been moved?

Comment: Selenium removed `Alert.authenticate` and supporting classes as of v3.8.0, which is stated in their [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG). Have you tried something like `windowAlert.sendKeys("username");` `windowAlert.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);` `windowAlert.sendKeys("password");` `windowAlert.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`?

Comment: Does site B opens in new tab or same tab?

Comment: @homersimpson - not tried that yet, will give it a try.

Comment: @Pradeephebbar everything opens in the same tab

Comment: @Josephcan you share the url

Comment: @Joseph Add HTML code for the button which redirects you to the authenticated page. I might have an idea how to handle it.

Comment: @Pradeephebbar I can't share the url - it's a company internal page

Comment: @Joseph, can you attach the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform some kind of workout. You will not explicitly invoke click on the button but instead, get its redirect attribute, use WebDriver's `get()` method and authenticated through it.

```
WebElement redirectionButton = driver.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9"));
String redirectionURL = redirectionButton.getAttribute("href"); //this part might be tricky. Href can be relative or absolute path. If it's relative, add current url to it
//optional, depends on href:
redirectionURL = driver.getCurrentUrl() + redirectionURL;

//now, since we have URL for the desired page, instead of clicking the button we will open the page.
driver.get("https://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + redirectionURL);
```

Comment: Hey folks - turns out that this popup was a fluke due to a setting in our internal systems being missing.  Once this has been looked at the problem went away.

Comment: @fenio, good hint. Maybe I would only emphasized the redirectionUrl part. It must be a URL to which you will be redirected after you log in, otherwise it will not work. We tried this successfully with selenium 3.141.59 and Selenium 68.0.